# How can I configure Azure storage to be available over the Internet?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I configured an SMB file share with Azure storage. I cannot connect to it from outside the Azure cloud. The connect instructions explicitly say

***To connect to this file share, run this command from any Windows virtual machine on the same subscription and location:***

How can I configure Azure file storage to be available over the public Internet?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using SMB 3.0 protocol, you should be able to access the files from outside of Azure by mounting the share as a network drive. You may have to open up TCP port 445 on your firewall though.

Please see this link for more details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/#mount-the-file-share

Answer (score 0):

To mount the file share from an on-premises client, you must first take these steps:

**1**.Install a version of Windows which supports SMB 3.0. Windows will leverage SMB 3.0 encryption to securely transfer data between your on-premises client and the Azure file share in the cloud.

**2**.Open Internet access for port 445 (TCP Outbound) in your local network, as is required by the SMB protocol

Then, on your on-premises client, you can just run the command as the connect instructions say:

```
net use <drive-letter>: \\<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net\<share-name> /u:<storage-account-name> <storage-account-key>
```

If you already enable port 445 but encounter the following error :
**System error 53 has occurred.  The network path was not found.**

You may need to check with your service provider, some Internet service providers may block port 445. You can refer to [this articles](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32346.azure-summary-of-isps-that-allow-disallow-access-from-port-445.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Port 445 was open on my router. It took me some time to find an additional option:
Netbios must be set to "allowed"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the case for me....

When I tried with in Azure (My VM is on Azure and My Storage account is also on the same region) with SMB 3.0, I have been getting mount errors. But when I changed the SMB Version to 2.1, it got succeed. See Below with Examples

Eg:

### Failing Command (with SMB 3.0 version) with in Azure

sudo mount -t cifs //storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net/shared /mnt/mount -o vers=3.0,username=xxxxxxx,password=xxxxxxxx,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777

> Result:
>
> mount error(11): Resource temporarily unavailable
> Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

#### Working Command (with SMB 2.1 version) with in Azure

sudo mount -t cifs //storageaccountname.file.core.windows.net/shared /mnt/mount -o vers=2.1,username=xxxxxxx,password=xxxxxxxx,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777

> Result:

It got mounted successfully